# Different BGP attributes that can be used for advertise

Tags: is-is

What are different BGP attributes can be used to advertise prefixes?

Comment: Any prefix announcement is essentially an agreement between you and your ISP. You need to talk with your ISP to agree on the best way to signal your routing preferences.

Comment: The best atrribute is the one your ISP agrees to use.

Comment: Yuo do realize there are many ways for a network to fail. And not all of them are interface failures, or gateway (IP of the other side) failures. BGP prepend **IS** the industry standard for doing this. No, you will not end up with zero traffic on the secondary link. And you don't want it to - it can fail for the same long list of reasons.

Comment: Is it just me or has a variant of this question been posted at least 4 times in the last few days?

Answer (score 1):

Your options are:

- accept that your traffic will be distributed over the two links, there's nothing wrong with that. It's the best way.
- work with your ISPs on the best way to setup this
- use some trick to only advertise your prefix to 1 ISP at a time

For example I once did a setup for the same question where:

- Router A advertise my prefix to ISP1 with a specific community
- Router B do receive this prefix from ISP 2 with my community, so it get the route with this community in its routing table (have to configure `allowas-in` for that)
- Router B has a route map that deny advertising of the prefix with the specific community

With this setup router B advertise the prefix to IPS 2 only if it is not receiving it (so if router A / IPS1 failed).
There's potential issues but I have such a setup running for several years now.